# Dropdownlist client side required validation (without model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**View**:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryItems", null, new { @class = "ddlcs" })
@Html.ValidationMessage("CategoryItems")
```

**Controller**:

```
var cat = from s in db.CategoryDbSet
          where s.IsActive == true
          orderby s.CatName
          select new { s.CatID, s.CatName };

var catListItems = cat.ToList()
                      .Select(c => new SelectListItem   
                             {
                                 Text = c.CatName,
                                 Value = c.CatID.ToString()
                             })
                       .ToList();

catListItems.Insert(0, new SelectListItem 
                           {
                               Text = "[--Select the category--]", 
                               Value = "" 
                           });

ViewBag.CategoryItems = catListItems;
```

I wish to enforce the required validation on the dropdown when someone selects the "Select the category" option during the save action. I am new to MVC framework and i am not sure where am i making the mistake ? This dropdown is not tied up with the Model.

Please suggest the soln.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This dropdown is not tied up with the Model.

That's the mistake. Validation in ASP.NET MVC works by decorating your view model properties with the respective attributes. For example if you want to make this dropdown required, you would decorate the corresponding property on your view model with the `[Required]` attribute.

So add the necessary properties to your existing view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int? SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }

    ... some other properties that your view might need
}
```

and then in your controller action populate this view model:

```
var model = new MyViewModel();
model.Categories = cat
    .ToList()
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem   
    {
        Text = c.CatName,
        Value = c.CatID.ToString()
    }).ToList();

return View(model);
```

and in your view use the strongly typed versions of the helpers:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedCategoryId,
    Model.Categories, 
    "[--Select the category--]", 
    new { @class = "ddlcs" }
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i am using EF to map the db objects into the Model. I start getting error message on other places wherever i use this model.  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'SelectedCategoryId'.

Comment: Now how would i able to fix this new Property for other places.

Comment: You should not be using your EF models in your views. That's what view models are intended for. Your controller could map between the 2.

Comment: On the listing page, i am doing something like this         public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "List of Advertisements";
            return View(db.ADVERTISEMENT.ToList());
        }

Comment: Could you please suggest how in the controller i could do the mapping?

Comment: Add a property to your view model that will contain the list of advertisements. Then in your controller set this property by taking it from the database: `model.Advertisements = db.ADVERTISEMENT.ToList();`. Finally return the view model to the view as shown in my answer.

Comment: How making a new property for advert list will solve the problem of error in another property ?

Comment: The view model is not bound to any EF context. The `SelectedCategoryId` property lives on the view model. So you won't get any error. The correct approach is not to use any of your domain models in the view model. You might also take a look at AutoMapper to simplify the mapping between your domain and view models.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43237/discussion-between-karan-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 0):

If you want only client side validation, you may do this:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules:{
        CategoryItems: 'required'
    }
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s5XAL/).

But I wouldn't suggest doing so as the client side validation is for better user experience and can be easily bypassed. The correct way to do this is described in Darin's answer, using dataannotations and view models.